# How to check if Variant not null before coerce it?

Tags: d, variant

I an getting from database data with `Variant` type. I need to check if variable have any data before coerce it.

```
  cargpspoint.speed = point[0].coerce!int;
```

if `point[0]` will be `null` I will get exception. I need to do coerce only if variable have value. There is long way with:

```
if(point[0].hasValue && point[0].peek!(int) !is null)
```

Is there any way to do it shorter? Or at last to not throw `Exception` if there is null inside.

https://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether the `typeid` inside is `void`.

```d
import std.variant : Variant;

struct CarGPSPoint
{
    int speed;
}

void main()
{
    Variant point[] = new Variant[5];

    CarGPSPoint cargpspoint;

    if ( point[0].type != typeid(void) )
        cargpspoint.speed = point[0].coerce!int;
}
```

Alternatively just catch and discard the exception.

```d
import std.variant : Variant, VariantException;

struct CarGPSPoint
{
    int speed;
}

void main()
{
    Variant point[] = new Variant[5];

    CarGPSPoint cargpspoint;

    try
        cargpspoint.speed = point[0].coerce!int;
    catch (VariantException e) {}
}
```